# How to use `Set.has` in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wanna check if a given string is in a typed `Set` like:

```
enum Fruit {
  AP = 'apple',
  OR = 'orange',
  BN = 'banana',
};

let validFruits = new Set(Object.values(Fruit));

function isValidFruit(v: string): boolean  {
  return validFruits.has(v);
                         ^ // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable 
                           // to parameter of type 'Fruit'.
}
```

I don't wanna use `find` since that iterates over all the values. How do I do this and keep the membership test at `O(1)`?

Comment: It should be ok to just `new Set<string>(enum.values)`?

Comment: does this work `validFruits.has(v as Fruit)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix this:

```
const validFruits = new Set<string>(Object.values(Fruit));
```

Another way to fix this:

```
function isValidFruit(v: string): boolean  {
  return validFruits.has(v as any);
}
```

Comment: I need to keep the `Set<Fruit>`

Comment: @SamR. got another one for ya.

Comment: :) Thanks. Technically true so I'll accept your answer since it answered my question but I think I need to rephrase my question as I was looking for a way to coerce a `string` value to its corresponding `enum`. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @SamR, what you are looking for is technically a type guard or assertion function. It is pretty normal to use casts in these types of functions, so I feel that this is a pretty idiomatic way to handle this. I would suggest you look into the drawbacks of `enum` (there's better tools these days) and how type guards are generally written. You'll find that my second example is pretty common.